# Find the value of $E[X^2Y]$.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X\in\{0,1\},Y\in\{3,4\}$ be discrete random variables, and their joint distrubtion be given as in the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 X/Y& \text{3} & \text{4} \\ \hline
\text{0} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{8} \\ \hline
\text{1} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{8} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Find $E[X^2Y]$.

What I did:

> We have that $\sum x_i^2y_iP(X^2Y=x_i^2y_i)=\sum x_i^2y_i P(X^2=x_i^2,Y=y_i)$

What do I do with $X^2$? Does it take the same probabilities as $X$ when calculating the $P(X^2=x_i,Y=y_i)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$
E(X^2Y)=\sum x^2yP(X=x,Y=y)
$$
where the summation is over the set $(x,y)\in\{0,1\}\times\{3,4\}$ and $P(X=x,Y=y)$ can be found from your joint distribution table.

Comment: Oh yea that is what I was doing wrong, so the answer should be $1\cdot 3\frac{1}{4}+1\cdot 4\frac{1}{8}$ right?

Comment: Yea but two of the four terms have a $0$ so those contributions are null, right?

Comment: @SebastianCor: That's correct!